# save data in html element dynamicaly

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am dynamically reading valued from db and append element in DOM,I below code i am reading one field and storing it in id e.g 11 in below sample . however there is one more field in table called comments , as what should i set it on html element so that i don't need to fire db query again for comment ??

```
 <div id="selectionbox" style="display:inline-block">
    <img style="display:inline-block" id="activity_image11" src="../images/Desert.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class1" id="11" style="display:inline-block">
</div>
```

I am getting many selectionbox as above which i am appending in DOM ,later i am fetching selected checkbox using ,

```
temp.push($( "div#"+this.id ).find( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).map(function() {
        return this.id
    }).get());
```

My problem is if i will store comment `in data-value="10"`  then how can i fetch those data fields???

Comment: what? please post more codes and lets us know what are you talking about.

Comment: @imsiso more details added please check

Comment: so you want to get id of a selected checkbox and run a query in background(without refreshing page) to get a comments related to an id? if yes it would not be so hard you can do it by ajax let me know if there is any problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you're trying to fetch the values from `data-value`

You can simple fetch data values like

```
$('#comments').data('value');
```

or

```
 $('#comments').attr('data-value');
```

Comment: user1671639 currently i dont have comment field , is there any way to use data in checkbox field and fetch data at the same time when i fetch selected checkbox.

Comment: in map function (return this.id) returns id of selected check box , how cani get comment of selected checkbox

Comment: @simmisimmi I can't get you, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CEv22/ and check whether this is what you're trying

Answer (score 1):

You can add one extra attribute in checkbox [data-value]. Your code will look like this:

```
<div id="selectionbox" style="display:inline-block">
    <img style="display:inline-block" id="activity_image11" src="../images/Desert.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class1" id="11" data-comment="some comments for 11" style="display:inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class1" id="12" data-comment="some comments for 12" style="display:inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class1" id="13" data-comment="BC" style="display:inline-block">
</div>
```

Then later you can fetch this value from checkbox:

```
$("#selectionbox  input[type=checkbox]:checked").attr("data-comment");
```

P.S. If comment data is big then instead of using new attribute I would recommend using  jQuery [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)